# Unable to install the package EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet version 1.1.0-preview4-final

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

When I try to install the package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet* version 1.1.0-preview4-final I have the error (translated from french) :

> The pakage Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
>   1.1.0-preview4-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'my web app project'

I have already check :

- *.NET Core 1.1 SDK* is installed on my computer
- My web app targets .NETCoreApp 1.1 framework
- All my NuGet packages are up to date

Environment info :

- Visual Studio 2017 RC
- ASP.NET Core Web Application, .NETCoreApp 1.1

[image: NuGet package list]

The few things I found about errors like this one included to update *project.json*, file I don't have in my solution.

I also try to add this line in my csproj :

```
 <ItemGroup><DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" /></ItemGroup>
```

Someone have an idea about what happens here ? How can I manage db migrations with .NETCore 1.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `MSbuild` (Visual Studio 2017) then you should use [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.1.0-preview4-final) in `1.0.0-msbuild3-final` verison

To do this, update your csproj and add the next line in the same *ItemGroup* than the NuGet package references :

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
```

Comment: I already tried but the line has to be in the same item group than the NuGet packages to work. It's working now.

Comment: There is no such requirement on item groups. You can add toolreferences in own item group too.